# Basic PIC circuit is not working

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I have just begun in the world of microcontrollers, and the first microcontroller. I chose to work with was the PIC from Microchip.  The PIC I am using is the PIC16F877A.  I am using MPLAB IDE and HI-TECH C.  I am trying to make an extremely simple program that turns on an LED. This is the code I am using:

```
#include<htc.h>
#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000
__CONFIG(UNPROTECT & PWRTDIS & WDTDIS & HS & LVPDIS); 

int main()
{
    TRISB0 = 0;
    RB0 = 1;
    while(1);
}
```

When I hook up the PIC to my circuit the LED does not turn on. Here is my circuit diagram and a picture of my circuit:

[image]

[image]

A few other notes about my circuit:

- I am using a 9 volt battery hooked up to a 7805 regulator for the power supply.
- I have measured the voltage coming from pin RB0 with a multimeter and it measures 0.0 V.
- If there is no problem with my circuit I could have programmed the chip wrong.
- My capacitors hooked up with my crystal are 22 pf, not 22 µf as in the schematic.
- I have put 100 µf capacitors between pins 11 and 12 and between 31 and 32.

Comment: Do you have a current limiting resistor for the led? A led with no resistor is like a short, either remove the led and use the multimeter to check the pin state or add a resistor in series with the led (try 270-330 Ohm)

Comment: i am using a red with a built in current limiting resistor

Comment: So the breadboard image you have provided is not your actual circuit? It shows a green led and no capacitors for the crystal (or are hidden underneath)

Comment: So let me get this straight: 1) You are able to write and read successfully. 2) Those load capacitors next to the crystal are surely not 22uF...

Comment: 1. Yes i can read and write correctly  2. I meant 22pF

Comment: 2. I suppose those caps are 22pF, and in the picture, they are hidden beneath the crystal itself.

Comment: Have you set the IO direction of the LED port to be output (maybe that is the default?) so that it can drive your green or red LED?

Comment: In my code this line     TRISB0 = 0;

Comment: What about supply decoupling caps for the chip? What about actually putting your xtal onto the breadboard right next to pin 13 and 14? Maybe an RC circuit for a power-on-reset might help?

Comment: Could you explain those points in detail

Comment: Can you please disconnect the led and measure the pin status with a multimeter? I don't see any red led with built-in resistor, I only see a green led that seems the normal type.

Comment: I have tested it with a multimeter 0 volts, i put in the red led after photo

Comment: +1 Andy re: decoupling caps. And don't you need a Config line? At least to turn off the watchdog and make sure the oscillator is set to XT.

Comment: In this tutorial http://electrosome.com/blinking-led-pic-microcontroller-hi-tech-c/ neither is included

Comment: @popgalop: Andy means at least have a 100nF capacitor between pins 11 and 12 (Vcc and Gnd) and likely between 32 and 31 as well. The default setup for the Config bits would indicate the PIC expects an RC oscillator. Without setting them somewhere it can't work... (I can go check the datasheet now)
Last comment - I understand. Decoupling is one of those things that you "can get away with" but isn't a good idea to try. And the tutorial might expect the CONFIG bits to be set somewhere in the GUI.

Comment: Scratch my comment about XT. I've checked the datasheet and it's HS for 8MHz. Try putting:

__CONFIG(FOSC_HS & WDTE_OFF & PWRTE_OFF & BOREN_OFF & LVP_OFF & WRT_OFF & CPD_OFF & CP_OFF)

after the #define.

Comment: Ok i put 100uf capacitors between pins 11 and 12 and between 31 and 32, what should the config bits be

Comment: You could test with the internal RC oscillator so you can remove and rule out your crystal components and connections.  When that works, add the crystal.

Comment: Does the PIC16F877A have an internal oscillator http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en010242

Comment: Maybe you should post the real photo of your circuit. The xtal part looks very suspicious.

Comment: Maybe you have damaged the pin when you used the green led without resistor (as shown in the image), can you try with a different mcu pin and even better in another port too?

Comment: It actually worked on pin RB1 for some reason, that seems odd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's impossible to put code in comments, I'll put my suggestion for code that sets the Config bits correctly here. The issue is I don't have this compiler so I cannot be certain of the names (LVPDIS as opposed to, say, LVP_OFF in assembly) but if I'm wrong, someone could comment(?)

```
#include <htc.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000

__CONFIG(UNPROTECT & PWRTDIS & WDTDIS & HS & LVPDIS);

int main()
{
    TRISB0 = 0;
    RB0 = 1;
    while(1);
}
```

Comment: i updated my code to this and the same problem still occurs

Comment: Sorry to hear this - my first PIC project was with a PIC16f88 which has an internal oscillator. As a last resort you could try the RC oscillator as shown on pg 146 of the datasheet. Change HS in the __CONFIG to RCCLK (I think) and use your 22pF capacitor with a 100k resistor. The oscillator will be in the 100s of kHz but something (anything!) might start!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried checking the clko pin to see if you are getting a clock signal? Hook a scope up to it and make sure the chip is even running. If you don't have a scope or usb logic analyzer, you *might* be able to see an LED glow slightly from that pin.

Have you measured the Vdd to make certain you are supply the correct power level (between 4.0 and 5.5)?

As RB0 is also an external interrupt pin, try moving the LED to pin34 and changing your code to use RB1 instead:

```
TRISB1 = 0;
RB1 = 1;
```

Comment: I dont have a scope, my multimeter says 5.01V as power level

Comment: try another pin (updated above)

Comment: What does your multimeter say if you measure pin 14 (to ground)? How did you program the chip, and did it verify?

Comment: It actually worked on pin RB1 for some reason, that seems odd

Comment: You could have a few things going on. You may need to disable all interrupts to use RB0 (GIE, PIE, and the external pin interrupt). Also, not sure if that pin is also an ADC pin, but if that's the case, you should clear the ANSEL register to make it a digital I/O.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no bypass cap in sight.  Put 100 nF to 1 µF ceramic directly between each power pin and ground.

   Showing only the pin numbers doesn't show us the pin function.  It's impossible to see what you have connected to what pin without looking up the pinout in the datasheet.  This information should be in your schematic.

   22 µF is about 6 orders of magnitude too much capacitance for the crystal and its drive circuit.  This will definitely keep the oscillator from running, and therefore the PIC from running.

   There is no resistor in series with the LED, so it will draw too much current.  That can load down the supply, damage the LED, and/or damage the PIC pin output driver.

   Note that any pin that can be a analog input wakes up that way by default.  I don't remember off the top of my head whether the pin you are trying to use is one of them, but it's a good idea to go to the A/D and/or comparator modules and make sure all pins are configured as digital.

Comment: +1 for commenting about needing the pin function in addition to showing the pin numbers.